# How to iterate over properties in Twig

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig

I'm using Symfony2. How can I iterate over properties? I found a solution adding a filter... is there any other and simple way to iterate over properties?

```
Plaza {#1647 ▼
  -id: 2
  -codigo: "27"
  -nombre: "AG. LAS PALMAS M"
  -razon: "M.Baez"
  -direccion: "Calle Alemania 76 - 1A"
  -localidad: "Las Palmas de Gran Canaria"
  -codpostal: "prueba quiza sobra campo"
  -cif: "B00000001"
  -provincia: "Gran Canaria"
  -tarifas: PersistentCollection {#1683 ▶}
}
```

When I add the filter in Twig, it throws this error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class
>   Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection could not be converted to string")

What I've tried is this:

```
public function getFilters()
{
    return array(
        new \Twig_SimpleFilter('md2html', array($this, 'markdownToHtml'), array('is_safe' => array('html'))),
        new \Twig_SimpleFilter('cast_to_array', array($this, 'objectFilter')),
    );
}
```

having this function:

```
public function objectFilter($stdClassObject) {
    // Just typecast it to an array
    $response = (array)$stdClassObject;

    return $response;
}
```

And in the twig template I do this:

```
            {% for key, value in plaza|cast_to_array %}
                {{ value }}
            {% endfor %}
```

Any help is welcome!

Comment: can you post what you have tried? Which filter have you used?  how?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've updated just now with extra info...